# Missing expression en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estoy haciendo un query: uso `pivot` y `listagg` para pasar unas filas a columnas.

El query así no me funciona, arroja `Missing Expression` cuando hago la subquery del `listagg`:

```sql
select 
  store_id, 
  store_desc, 
  type_id, 
  premise_desc, 
  value_id 
from 
  premises_stores 
  inner join premises on premises_stores.premise_id = premises.premise_id 
where 
  1 = 1
) P PIVOT(
  max(value_id) for premise_desc in (
    select 
      concat(
        listagg(
          '''' || rtrim(premise_desc) || ''' as "' || rtrim(premise_desc), 
          '",'
        ) within group (
          order by 
            order_id
        ), 
        '"'
      ) premise_desc 
    from 
      premises
  )
```

Pero si eso que está dentro del paréntesis del `IN` le coloco el resultado aparte

```
'Senasa' as "Senasa",'PTR' as "PTR",'Bromatologia - Modelo' as "Bromatologia - Modelo",'Bromatologia - Zoofito' as "Bromatologia - Zoofito",'Bromatologia - CIPPA' as "Bromatologia - CIPPA",'Bromatologia - Lacteos' as "Bromatologia - Lacteos",'Bromatologia - Detalle' as "Bromatologia - Detalle",'Sanitario' as "Sanitario",'TPC' as "TPC",'TPC - Listado' as "TPC - Listado",'Remito' as "Remito",'PT - CUVE' as "PT - CUVE",'PTR - CUVE' as "PTR - CUVE",'Documentos Adicionales' as "Documentos Adicionales"
```

Me sale ok:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en tu caso y en la sentencia que añades, la cláusula "PIVOT" no está correctamente formateada. La sintáxis básica de la cláusula "PIVOT" es:

```
PIVOT (función_agregado(columna_agregada)
       FOR columna_rotada IN (valores_rotados))
```

Debe ir seguida de una consulta que seleccione los datos que se van a rotar y luego especificar los valores que se van a rotar en la columna "FOR" y la función de agregado que se va a aplicar en la columna "IN".

```
SELECT store_id, store_desc, type_id, premise_desc, value_id
FROM premises_stores
INNER JOIN premises
ON premises_stores.premise_id = premises.premise_id
WHERE 1 = 1
) P
PIVOT (MAX(value_id)
       FOR premise_desc IN ('Senasa', 'PTR', 'Bromatologia - Modelo', 'Bromatologia - Zoofito', 'Bromatologia - CIPPA', 'Bromatologia - Lacteos', 'Bromatologia - Detalle', 'Sanitario', 'TPC', 'TPC - Listado', 'Remito', 'PT - CUVE', 'PTR - CUVE', 'Documentos Adicionales')
)
```